# How to make a List<string> {get;set;} per thread,

Tags: c#

I have a class that requires dynamically setting a List.  I also call this class 10 or so different times using Threading.

`public static List<string> MyList {get;set;}`

I'm new to threading, however, as I've been told this is unsafe.  The question I have is how do I make an instance of `MyList`  per thread?

An example would be awesome!

Comment: That is what instances are for. If you really must have an instance per thread then keep a dictionary of your lists according to thread id or thread local storage.

Comment: What are you trying to do? There's a huge difference between having a single static field and having an instance per thread. It's not just something you change because of threading issues. It also affects how data is shared between threads.

Comment: @MarkByers What I want to do, is when I use my parallel for each, I run a specific mysql query based on results from a previous `void`.  Those results then create `MyList` which the rest of the class my use to perform its functionality

Comment: @M.Babcock You should read some docs about ThreadStatic

Comment: @L.B - Fair enough, that's why I left it as a comment. It fills a niche that I have yet to encounter, though if I had encountered it I'd likely try to find my own way to handle it (unnecessarily). Coming from a C++ background TLS is the closest thing I had to use cross-platform, so apparently they've improved that nightmare for C#.

Comment: I've used TLS before to control a scope, akin to the [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx), which should be thread-specific.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`ThreadStatic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx) attribute.

```
[ThreadStatic] private static List<string> _myList;

public static List<string> MyList {
  get { return _myList; }
  set { _myList = value; }
}
```

Also, usually it's better for the containing class to have control over the collection; this would mean no externally-visible setter and a getter that returns either a copy or a read-only collection.

But, **this might not have the effect you intend**. Each thread will have its own copy of the collection. Maybe what you need is to take a look at *locks* or rethink your design.

Comment: I want each thread to contain its own copy, it only gets set once and should never be set agian, however this has to be unique per thread

Comment: will give it a go, here might be a stupid question I see [ThreadStatic] obviously starts the code by how do I know that [Threadstatic] ends at the final } of MyList and doesnt effect the rest of the code

Comment: Well, you need some kind of lifecycle-control; if your thread is re-used, your collection will still be there. And if you're using the thread pool then be sure that your thread will be reused.

Comment: Oh, and by the way the `ThreadStatic` attribute only applies to the `_myList` field, it doesn't apply to the property. But, since the property uses the field, it "inherits" this characteristic as well. I'll reformat the code to make it more obvious.